# Data pre-processing on test files

Tags: categorical-data, missing-data, data-preprocessing

I am working on a classification problem. I have a training file with a label and a separate test file without a label field.

I needed to remove some rows that contained missing values from the train file. Should I also remove rows that contain missing values from the test file as well? The missing values are categorical and are indicated as "Unknown" in the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to handle missing categorical data. The way you choose can also depend upon the requirements of the problem at hand.

One way to handle missing categorical values is just to ignore them (typically when the dataset is large and less number of records are missing).

If there are so many values missing, and the variable is not significant, then you can just ignore the variable.

You can also predict the missing variable by developing a model.

Or you can just impute the missing categorical variable with a new category (like "missing_value") or replace it with the most frequently occurring value during the preprocessing stage.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is focused on the test file, and what should be done to it

Comment: @AfiaR.S. You can do the same for test file too. But remember to look for the value to impute from the training set only. (like if you choose to impute the most frequent value, choose the most frequent value occurring in the training dataset, not test data). I hope this helps.